# Router unable to obtain IP

Tags: ssh, ip, network-interface, adsl-router, vdsl

I own a d-link router model DSL-2877AL.. used to work flawlessly in the past 8 months but recently the routers internet light will always stay red which indicates a failed PPPoe negotiation.. VDSL2 syncs without a problem at 70mbps down 5mbps up but the router is unable to communicate with the ISP to obtain a a wan IP..I tried to call my ISP they told me it's a router problem..I called D-Link they told me it's an ISP problem..but I think the problem might be with the router itself..I checked the logs and I noticed an error "unrecognized option nas8_2" ..I figured that the router is trying to communicate over a non existent interface..can anyone help me and tell me how to create a PTM interface using the SSH CLI? I tried using the 2684ctl command but it only creates an ATM interface.. VDSL2 can't communicate over an ATM interface..I need to create a PTM one manually..any help would appreciated

Comment: Have you tried resetting to the factory default settings?

Comment: yeah i did that 5 or 6 times ..no effect..the router still shows "unrecognized option na8_2" on it's logs

Comment: Do you own your router or is it provided by your ISP?

Comment: i own it............